# Lumen @ foreach Invalid argument

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

When I use this code:

```
 $body=$request->all();
        $contacts = json_decode($request->get('contacts'), true);
        $user_contacts = array_flatten($this->_model->scan_contacts($this->_user->user_id, $contacts));
        $nonsync_contacts = array();
        foreach ($contacts as $contact) {

            if (!in_array($contact["mobile"], $user_contacts)) {
                $nonsync_contacts[] = $contact;
            }
        }
```

I get this error message:

```
ErrorException in Arr.php line 493:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

How do I avoid this error?

Comment: show the ouput of this print_r($contacts)

Comment: i am sure $contacts is not an array or it may be empty

Answer (score 0):

```
$body=$request->all();
$contacts = json_decode($request->get('contacts'), true);
$user_contacts = array_flatten($this->_model->scan_contacts($this->_user->user_id, $contacts));
$nonsync_contacts = array();
if(is_array($contacts)) {
    foreach ($contacts as $contact) {

        if (!in_array($contact["mobile"], $user_contacts)) {
            $nonsync_contacts[] = $contact;
        }
    }
}
```

Check is a `$contacts` array and after that loop it(because it can be null or something else)

Comment: $contact in print_r() value is empty

Answer (score 0):

You should check your `$contacts` value before `foreach`-ing:

```
$contacts = json_decode($request->get('contacts'), true);
$contacts = is_array($contacts) ? $contacts : [];
```

Or simply right before `foreach`

```
foreach (($contacts ?: []) as $contact)
```

If you're using PHP 7.0, use null coalesce operator

```
foreach (($contacts ?? []) as $contact)
```

As `json_decode` will always return `null` the value cannot be decoded due to invalid JSON structure or he encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit. Be sure that your `$request->get('contacts')` never returns **ANY** boolean value.